# libgit2: Get unmodified file from last commit

Tags: libgit2

I'm looking into creating a text editor and would like the editor to display an indicator for lines which have been modified. The modifications need to be with respect to the last time the file was checked into git. This lead me to libgit2, is there a way this library can give me an original, unmodified file with respect to the last time it was commited? If my editor can get the original file, it will be able to know which lines the user has changed.